# constexpr static member pointer compiles with gcc and clang, but not with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, constexpr

The following class

```cpp
class Foo
{
    int member;
    inline static constexpr auto r = &Foo::member;
};
```

compiles with gcc 10.2 and clang 11.0.0. However, trying to compile the same code with MSVC v19.28 results in following error:

```
error C2327: 'Foo::member': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
error C2065: 'member': undeclared identifier
```

Is this a compiler bug or am I running into undefined behavior? All compilers have been run in C++17 mode.
(https://godbolt.org/z/Gv1KW7 on Compiler Explorer)

Comment: Compile with latest though [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4jWqK6).

Comment: And moving the member outside of the class make it happy too [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wdf7d9), seems really a bug from msvc.

Comment: I've seen quite a few bugs around this kind of thing (mostly relating to nested types, but all involving naming class members statically) in the last few versions of VS.

Comment: I don't see how that code can make sense - `int member` is a instance-specific variable, and `r` is a static variable - how could `r` be initialized with the address of a member, if no instances exists yet? And the address of which instance's `member`??

Comment: @Aganju `r` is a static variable containing a pointer to member, which points to that class member regardless of the instance (hence why it has to be used with the operators `.*` or `->*`), not a general pointer pointing to some instance variable.

Comment: @Aganju: `auto` would be `int Foo::*`.

Comment: @Fulgen  Aganju is right, though, remove the constexpr, and this would never compile.  This is a very strong hint your code is crossing the boundaries of undefined behavior.  Undefined behavior means only that the standard does not define behavior for a piece of code. There should be no surprise that different compilers will behave differently with this piece of code.  It is simply not portable for one compiler to another.

Comment: Illegal code as far as I know. But a long standing gcc extension, that clang also support.